# Google Maps API searching for places based on city using dropdown (select option) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hello I want to ask about google maps API. Previously, I was a beginner in using Google Maps API. I want to make a search for places by city using `select option`.

I've tried reading documentation and a few videos on youtube, other posts on stackoverflow, but none of them fit what I want.

I want to make maps like below. when I search by `select option`, the selected city will appear. And when i click on the marker, i will see place descriptions such as photos, place names, and descriptions.

[image]

Is it possible for me to make a feature like that? I really stuck with what I make, I've made some code like the one below. please help me, i really need your help.

```js
let map;
        let places;
        let infoWindow;
        let markers = [];
        let autocomplete;
        const countryRestrict = {
            country: "tangerang"
        };
        const MARKER_PATH = "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_green";
        const hostnameRegexp = new RegExp("^https?://.+?/");
        const cities = {
            jakarta: {
                center: {
                    lat: -6.186286,
                    lng: 106.822746
                },
                zoom: 12
            },
            tangerang: {
                center: {
                    lat: -6.336135,
                    lng: 106.676924
                },
                zoom: 11
            }
        };

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: cities["tangerang"].zoom,
                center: cities["tangerang"].center,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                fullscreenControl: false,
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: document.getElementById("info-content")
            });

            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                document.getElementById("autocomplete"), {
                    types: ["(cities)"],
                    componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
                }
            );

            places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", onPlaceChanged);

            document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("change", setAutocompleteCountry);
}

function setAutocompleteCountry() {
            const country = document.getElementById("country").value;

            if (country == "all") {
                autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
                    country: []
                });
                map.setCenter({
                    lat: 15,
                    lng: 0
                });
                map.setZoom(2);
            } else {
                autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
                    country: country
                });
                map.setCenter(cities[country].center);
                map.setZoom(cities[country].zoom);
            }
        }
```

```css
#mapsContent {
    position: relative;
}

#mapsContent #controls {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 9;
}

#mapsContent #controls .city {
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #acacac;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#contactContent #mapsContent #controls h4 {
    color: #16215C;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
}

#contactContent #mapsContent #controls #country {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#map {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: #CACACA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="mapsContent">
      <div id="controls">
          <div class="city">
               <h4>Kota</h4>
          </div>
          <select id="country">
               <option value="all">All</option>
               <option value="jakarta">DKI Jakarta</option>
               <option value="tangerang" selected>Tangerang</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with your code snippet: `InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement`.  The `autocomplete` element **must** be a `<input>` element.  Currently your code (`document.getElementById("autocomplete")`) is looking for an element with `id="autocomplete`, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Also another javascript error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: onPlaceChanged is not defined`,  because `onPlaceChanged` isn't defined.

Comment: that's why I asked because I didn't use the text input type here. I use the dropdown (select option). I am confused how the implementation @geocodezip

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add-autocomplete) The Autocomplete constructor takes two arguments:
An HTML input element of type text and An options argument.  It won't work with anything else.  If you have known strings, you don't want to use autocomplete, you just want to do a places API search from that text field.

Comment: You can center your map based on the dropdown using either the places api or the geocoder.  It is not clear where you are expecting the markers to come from.

Comment: [Example of zooming to a US state based on a `<select>`](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2stateSelectList.html) (using the geocoder)

Comment: And how i input markers?

Comment: That was my question for you.  Where are you expecting them to come from? What do they represent?  Google's places? Something else?

Comment: Are you looking for something more like this: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_radiusSearch.html

Comment: So, in one city there are 1-3 places, or 1 city has only 1 place, like that. So, when I select the city 'Jakarta' it displays the city of Jakarta and there is a marker map of several places in Jakarta. And when i click on a place marker, details of that place will appear

Comment: So do you know these places coordinates/addresses? Or do you only know the city's coordinates and would like to search nearby places? If nearby places, what kind of places are you searching for (i.e. establishments, cafes, etc.)?

Comment: This is a place that still has corporate ties, so I have the coordinates. So, what I want, maybe I'll have a multidimensional object or array. So in an array or object, for example jakarta. I have the Jakarta coordinate itself, which includes the coordinates of the related company. So when I chose Jakarta, several related company coordinates appeared. Like the example image I put in post above @RickyCuarez

Comment: I removed your API key from the code you provided, please don't share them on public sites.

Comment: @.geocodezip take api key there, he edited my post. I just write YOUR_API_KEY when i create this post @jabamantaro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get achieve your desired results, you will have to make use of [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) and [Place photo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos) requests. As indicated, after selecting a city, your known corporate places will show markers and infowindows that shows the details and initial photo of the place.

The places of each city are in a JSON object, however, it will only have each unique place ids. When you modify the JSON object, you can make use of the [place id finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) inputting your company address to get the place's unique place_id. It is alright to cache the place ID as indicated in the [service specific terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms#5.-places-api) of google

To also minimize costs further, you will see that I indicated the `fields` parameter to only get the data that you need. You can check all the available fields [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-data-fields).

Here is the JSFiddle sample for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/pintsik999/0vjbep7h/

You can also see the code below:

```js
"use strict";

let map;
let cities;
let markers = [];

var citiesObj = {
  "cities": [{
    "key": "DKI Jakarta",
    "value": {
      "city": "jakarta",
      "center": {
        "lat": -6.186286,
        "lng": 106.822746
      },
      "zoom": 12,
      //Since you know at least the address of the places, you can go here to get the unique place ID: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder 
      "places": [{
          "place_id": "ChIJB9Y8liH0aS4RemVuMOm5PFA"
        },
        {
          "place_id": "ChIJA7dLFoL2aS4Rbu2LGxzIbAA"
        }
      ]
    }

  }, {
    "key": "Tangerang",
    "value": {
      "city": "tangerang",
      "center": {
        "lat": -6.336135,
        "lng": 106.676924
      },
      "zoom": 11,
      "places": [{
        "place_id": "ChIJS3fhJPzkaS4RF8UTWV8LnLY"
      }]
    }
  }]
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -6.336135,
      lng: 106.676924,
    },
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
  });
  cities = document.getElementById("city");
  cities.options.add(new Option('Select City', ''))
  //value of cities are JSON objects to customize center and zoom of the map upon selection
  for (var i = 0; i < citiesObj.cities.length; i++) {
    cities.options.add(new Option(citiesObj.cities[i].key, JSON.stringify(citiesObj.cities[i].value)))
  }
}

//add markers and infowindows on the places in the selected city
function cityChanged() {
  //Hide/reset markers when city selection has changed.
  deleteMarkers();
  var selectedCity = JSON.parse(cities.value);
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(selectedCity.center));
  //instantiate placedetail service
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedCity.places.length; i++) {
    const request = {
      placeId: selectedCity.places[i].place_id,
      //adding the fields parameter will allow you to specify the details that you only need so that you wont be billed unnecessarily for extra data that you don't use. Check all the available fields here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-data-fields
      fields: ["name", "formatted_address", "place_id", "geometry", "photos"],
    };
    service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        addMarker(place);
      }
    });
  }
}

function addMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    map: map
  });
  addInfoWindow(marker, place);
  markers.push(marker);
}

function addInfoWindow(marker, place) {
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infowindow.setContent(
      "<img src='" + place.photos[0].getUrl() + " width='300' height='400'>" +
      "<div><strong>" +
      place.name +
      "</strong><br>" +
      "Place ID: " +
      place.place_id +
      "<br>" +
      place.formatted_address +
      "</div>"
    );
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

function deleteMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- REPLACE API KEY PLACEHOLDER -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      City:
      <select id="city" onchange="cityChanged()">
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's 2 dropdowns. I only need 1, which is the city dropdown. Can it only be 1 dropdown?

Comment: Done. I have updated both the code and the sample for your reference.

Comment: I see the option is obtained from javascript, because the html (select) is empty. can it be made directly in the html my friend? @RickyCuarez

Comment: actually, I have dozens of cities, not just 2. If I look at your code above, it will be very long. is there any best practice to handle it?

Comment: That's weird, the comment of the guy who +1 as well as mine were deleted? In any case, I had further optimize the code above. It is best practice to populate a JSON object instead of putting all those data in the HTML. I have made it so that you would only have to touch that single JSON object if you ever need to add or change the places. Just follow the format and you should be good.

Comment: that's the best practice I mean. Thank you very much for all the efforts you have put in to deal with this problem, I know it takes time and thought. Thank you very much and I hope this post will be useful for others in the future! :) @RickyCuarez